# How does torch.unique() at a low level work on tensors?

Tags: pytorch, vectorization

There is no open-source code of the torch.unique() function, How is it implemented and what kind of algorithms does it use in low-level code to extract the unique elements of the input tensor and the counts for each unique element?

Comment: A pointer: the function signature seems to have been fixed in the docs in [this pull request](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/66132) which shows that the source of `torch.unique` comes from [line 660 of torch/functional.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/2416bff104ca59759f019e40e329135f8e94dca0/torch/functional.py#L660) in this particular commit.